# Chrome freezing on custom built pc

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, freeze

Aight so i posted this a while ago with another problem but it turns out that not only did i fix said problem but it was against the rules or something as well.

But i have this problem with google chrome, and im not sure what to do. It happens multiple times a day and its very inconvenient. So basically, when im browsing youtube, sometimes when clicking on links, going back a page or even skipping to a point in a video chrome just freezes. Eventually it stops responding and im forced to close it out, tho i do know how to get rid of this sort of. When it locks up, i go into task manager and view the multiple processes of chrome, then i kill the top one (that just so happens to always exceed 200mb of memory) and it unfreezes for some reason. This doesnt happen on any other browser. Ive already reinstalled chrome (and windows) multiple timesso it either has to do with my mobo (msi b450 tomahawk max) or my hard drive (kingston ae1200 500gb). Help :T

Comment: Does this occur with other browsers as well, such as Firefox/Opera/Edge etc?

Comment: Nope imma edit the post with a bit more information

Answer (score 0):

Hard to troubleshoot with just the information you've provided. There could be lots of reasons. In the past when I've hit problems like these where the potential solutions just keep pouring in yet none of them end up working. I've learnt it's best to just format the system or abandon the app. Because it honestly takes less time to just reinstall and download the apps, than it does to scratch your head for a week and try all sorts of voodoo that ends up just causing more issues.

I very highly doubt it has anything to do with your hardware.